# One of my ros node emits [Errno 111] Connection refused in docker container

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, docker, jetson

I am currently developing ros packages in docker system.
The environment I am using is ROS noetic, Ubuntu focal on a docker container
One of my package is failing. I seems it is due to failing to get /initialpose but I could not figure why. Any suggestions or guesses will be really help

Below is par of error log in master.log

```
rosmaster.master][INFO] 2023-12-07 07:22:19,583: -SERVICE [/rviz/load_config] /rviz rosrpc://desktop:43579
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2023-12-07 07:22:19,584: -SERVICE [/rviz/reload_shaders] /rviz rosrpc://desktop:43579
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2023-12-07 07:22:19,606: publisherUpdate[/move_base_simple/goal] -> http://desktop:34559/ []
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2023-12-07 07:22:19,624: publisherUpdate[/initialpose] -> http://desktop:42573/ []
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2023-12-07 07:22:19,625: publisherUpdate[/initialpose] -> http://desktop:42573/ []: sec=0.00, exception=[Errno 111] Connection refused
[rosmaster.threadpool][ERROR] 2023-12-07 07:22:19,628: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosmaster/threadpool.py", line 218, in run
    result = cmd(*args)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosmaster/master_api.py", line 210, in publisher_update_task
    ret = xmlrpcapi(api).publisherUpdate('/master', topic, pub_uris)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1109, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1450, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1153, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1165, in single_request
    http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1278, in send_request
    self.send_content(connection, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1308, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 922, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

This is my cmd to run docker

```
sudo docker run -it --name noetic-r35-3 -d --privileged --network=host \
                    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
                    -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY -v=/dev:/dev -v=$(pwd)/dockerWorkspace:/workspace \
                    img-noetic-r35-2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share what command you're using to run the docker image?